# How do I get the text for a node from a data column?

Tags: pgfplots, pgfplotstable, nodes-near-coords

I have a table with three columns. I am plotting a dot plot on two of the columns, and I want to sign the points from the top, taking the data from the first column (column with index 0) for the signature. How can this be done? (It would be good with minimum memory usage).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
Interstellar medium, 1, 1
Ionosphere, 1e11, 5e-2
TOKAMAK, 1e13, 1e3
Smoldering discharge, 1e15, 2
Metals, 1e25, 1e-2
Solar core, 1e26, 1e3
White dwarf core, 1e30, 2e4
\end{filecontents*}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            ymode=log,
            xmode=log,
            xlabel={$n$, cm$^{-3}$},
            ylabel={$T$, eV},
            xmin=1e-5,
            xmax=1e30,
            ymin=1e-4,
        ]
        
       \pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma, header=false]{data.dat}\datatable
       \addplot[blue, only marks] table[x index = 1, y index = 2] \datatable node[above, font=\scriptsize] {
       % content of first (index 0) column
       };
% This is how it should work if the data is not taken from the table

%       \addplot[blue, only marks] coordinates { (1e13, 1e3) } node[above, font=\scriptsize] {TOKAMAK};
%
%       \addplot[blue, only marks] coordinates { (1e15, 2) } node[above, font=\scriptsize] {Smoldering discharge};
%
%       \addplot[blue, only marks] coordinates { (1e11, 0.05) } node[above, font=\scriptsize] {Ionosphere};
%
%       \addplot[blue, only marks] coordinates { (1e26, 1e3) } node[above, font=\scriptsize] {Solar core};
%
%       \addplot[blue, only marks] coordinates { (1e25, 1e-2) } node[above, font=\scriptsize] {Metals};
%
%       \addplot[blue, only marks] coordinates { (1e30, 2e4) } node[above left, font=\scriptsize] {White dwarf core};
%
%       \addplot[blue, only marks] coordinates { (1, 1) } node[above, font=\scriptsize, text width=3cm, align=center] {Interstellar medium};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I directly use `pgfplots` without `\pgfplotstableread`. You need to include `nodes near coords` key and set the plot style as `scatter`. You also need to specify the `point meta` as `explicit symbolic` then specify the `meta index` equal to 0. You could adjust every node style by using `nodes near coords style` key or change individual node style by using `coordinate style/.condition` key.

Here is a working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} 
\begin{filecontents*}{data.dat}
Interstellar medium, 1, 1
Ionosphere, 1e11, 5e-2
TOKAMAK, 1e13, 1e3
Smoldering discharge, 1e15, 2
Metals, 1e25, 1e-2
Solar core, 1e26, 1e3
White dwarf core, 1e30, 2e4
\end{filecontents*}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymode=log,
    xmode=log,
    xlabel={$n$, cm$^{-3}$},
    ylabel={$T$, eV},
    xmin=1e-5,
    xmax=1e30,
    ymin=1e-4,
]
\addplot[
scatter,
nodes near coords,
nodes near coords style={font=\scriptsize},
coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==0}{xshift=0.3cm},
coordinate style/.condition={\coordindex==6}{xshift=-1.2cm},
blue, only marks, 
point meta=explicit symbolic
] table [header=false,meta index=0,x index = 1, y index = 2,col sep=comma] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]